# Editing Stashed Action VS Tweaking Strip Actions

Tags: nla-editor

What is the difference between "Editing Stashed Action" and "Tweaking Strip Actions"?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Start Tweaking Strips Action:** The contents of Action strips can be edited, but you must be in Tweak Mode to do so. The keyframes of the action can then be edited in the Dope Sheet.

**Start Editing Stashed Action**: It will enter and exit Tweak Mode as usual, but will also make sure that the action can be edited in isolation (by flagging the NLA track that the action strip comes from as being “solo”). This is useful for editing stashed actions, without the rest of the NLA Stack interfering.